# Calculate the LDA in one of the lecturer notes is wrong?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

One of the lecturer notes online about LDA [LDA step by step](http://www.di.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid437773.pdf)

In Slide 25.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix multiplication is correct. The answer given in the slides is the *normalized* version, with unit norm, directing towards positives, i.e. $$\sqrt{0.9088^2+0.4173^2}\approx 1$$
In LDA, it'll be easier if you have a unit vector to project on, but, I think presenting as if it is the result of the given matrix multiplication is wrong and causes confusion.

Comment: How to get the nromalized version from the matrix multiplication?

Comment: it is the normalised version of the final result

Comment: how do you calculate the `normalised version of the final results`?

Comment: take the l2-norm and divide by it

Comment: sorry. What is `l2`? I cannot figure out.

Comment: It’s the sqrt of sum of squares of the elements in the vector

Comment: thanks. I mean how from the multiplication matrix `-1.70738, -0.7839` get to `0.9088, 0.4173`?

Comment: L2-norm of $[-1.70738, -0.7839]$ is $1.8787$. If you divide it by this number you'll get $[-0.9088, -0.4173]$. And, they also negated the final result because the direction (i.e. positive or negative) doesn't matter. They omitted these normalisation steps, this is not the result of the multiplication.

Comment: thanks. I finally got it. I presume that is called `Vector normalisation`. in order to plot a plane. I have another question about LDA lecturer notes which make me very confused. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466952/calculation-of-covariance-for-both-lda-lecturer-notes-is-different